# Metanilpotent groups and saturated formation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Class of all metanilpotent groups is a saturated formation ?
How do I prove

Comment: I would just verify the definition. You may find the nilpotent residual helpful as it has a very easy to use definition and good properties under homomorphisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do a residual proof. You can find the general version of this in Doerk-Hawkes. This is called the “formation product”, described in IV.1.7 page 337, and happens to equal the “Fitting product” as long as the quotient groups come from a Fitting formation.

**Definition:** $\newcommand{\nilres}[1]{\gamma_\infty\left({#1}\right)}$ $G$ is metanilpotent iff $\nilres{G}$ is nilpotent, where $\nilres{G}$ is the intersection of the lower central series of $G$.

In particular, $\nilres{H} \leq \nilres{G}$ and $\nilres{G/N} =\nilres{G}N/N$ and $\nilres{M}\nilres{N}=\nilres{MN}$ for $H \leq G$ and $M,N \unlhd G$. Since the class of nilpotent groups is closed under subgroups, quotients, normal products, and Frattini extensions, we get that metanilpotent subgroups are as well. That is, metanilpotent groups form a subgroup closed saturated Fitting formation.

Metanilpotent is closed under subgroups since $H \leq G$ implies $\nilres{H} \leq \nilres{G}$ and $\nilres{G}$ is nilpotent by definition of metanilpotent, and $\nilres{H}$ is nilpotent since the class of nilpotents are closed under subgroups. The others follow similarly.

Metanilpotent is closed under quotient groups since $N \unlhd G$ implies $\nilres{G/N} = \nilres{G}N/N \cong \nilres{G} / (\nilres{G} \cap N)$ is a quotient of a nilpotent group ($\nilres{G}$ which is nilpotent since $G$ is metanilpotent) and so $\nilres{G/N}$ is nilpotent since the class of nilpotent groups is closed under quotients.

Metanilpotent is closed under normal products: If $M,N \unlhd G$ and $M,N \in \mathcal{F}$, then $\nilres{M}, \nilres{N}$ are nilpotent by definition of metanilpotent. Also $\nilres{M},\nilres{N} \unlhd G$ as since $\nilres{M}$ is a characteristic subgroup of $M$. Since nilpotent groups are closed under normal products, $\nilres{M}\nilres{N}$ is nilpotent. Since $\nilres{MN}=\nilres{M}\nilres{N}$, we get that $MN$ is metanilpotent. Hence metanilpotent is closed under normal products.

Meta nilpotents is closed under Frattini extensions: If $G/\Phi(G)$ is metanilpotent, then $\nilres{G/\Phi(G)} = \nilres{G}\Phi(G)/\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent by definition of metanilpotent, but then $\nilres{G}\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent by Gaschütz's result, and $\nilres{G}\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent since nilpotents are closed under normal products.

Comment: **Definition:** $\newcommand{\nilres}[1]{\gamma_\infty\left({#1}\right)}$ $G$ is metanilpotent iff $\nilres{G}$ is nilpotent. $\qquad$ I Want The book Write this definition.I read your proof its very good and i learn all of them.tnx

Comment: I see this definition $\\$$\;G\;$ is metanilpotent iff there exists $\;N\lhd G\;$ s.t. that both $\,N\,,\,G/N\;$ are nilpotent $\\$ These two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. For a finite group, $G/N$ is nilpotent iff $\nilres{G} \leq N$. Also if $\nilres{G} \leq N$ and $N$ is nilpotent, then $\nilres{G}$ (a subgroup) is nilpotent.

Comment: ok,I need the proof of  $G/N$ nilpotent iff $\nilres{G} ‎\leq N$ ?

Comment: $G$ is nilpotent iff $\nilres{G}=1$ by definition of nilpotent. $\nilres{G/N} = \nilres{G}N/N$ is 1 iff $\nilres{G}N=N$ iff $\nilres{G} \leq N$.

Comment: Parden me. I read all proof. i have just one question. in the definition of formation we have  $\qquad$                                                             1)If $G\in \mathcal{F}$ and $N\lhd $ then $G/N\in \mathcal{F}$                                                     $\qquad$2)If $G/N$, $G/M$ both them belong $\mathcal{F}$ then $G/(M\cap N) \in\mathcal{F}$    $\qquad$ In your proof(1) is hold. Why (2) is hold

Comment: If $G/M$ and $G/N$ are in $\mathcal{F}$ then so are the isomorphic groups $G/M \times N/N$ and $M/M \times G/N$. Since $G/M \times N/N, M/M \times G/N \unlhd G/M \times G/N$ and are in $\mathcal{F}$, their normal product, $G/M \times G/N$, is also in $\mathcal{F}$. Also $\{ (gM,gN) \in G/M \times G/N \} \leq G/M \times G/N$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ since $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under subgroups, and $G/(M \cap N) \cong \{ (gM,gN) \in G/M \times G/N \}$ is in $\mathcal{F}$. I explained this in the $p$-length one answer. I show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a subgroup closed saturated Fitting formation.

Comment: Hi. I have another question, Why $G/N\times G/M \in \mathcal{F}$. i read your proof carfully. i jaust know if $G\in \mathcal{F}$ and $M, N \lhd G$ then $MN \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: "Closed under normal products" does not require $G \in \mathcal{F}$.  Just $M,N \in \mathcal{F}$ and $M,N \unlhd G$ implies $MN \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Oh, my proof was broken. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas (too long for a comment):

$\;G\;$ is metanilpotent iff there exists $\;N\lhd G\;$ s.t. that both $\,N\,,\,G/N\;$ are nilpotent .

If $\;|G|<\infty\;\;$  is $\;G/\Phi(G)\;$ metanilpotent ? Well, this is so iff

$$\exists\,M/\Phi(G)\lhd G/\Phi(G)\;\;\text{s.t. both}\;\;M/\Phi(G)\;,\;\left(G/\Phi(G)\right)\left(M/\Phi(G)\right)$$

are nilpotent. But

$$\left(G/\Phi(G)\right)\left(M/\Phi(G)\right)\cong G/M$$

So $\,G/\Phi(G)\;$ is metanilpotent iff

$$\exists\;M\lhd G\;\;s.t.\,\,\Phi(G)\le M\;\;\text{and s.t. both}\;\,M/\Phi(G)\;,\;G/M\;\;\text{are nilpotent}$$

From the above is clear that we **cannot** have Fit$(G)\le M\;$ , as then $\,G/M\;$ isn't nilpotent , so it all boils down to check whether  there exists

$$\Phi(G)\le M\lneq \text{Fit}(G)\;,\;\;M\lhd G\;,\;\;M/\Phi(G)\;,\;G/M\;\;\text{nilpotent}$$

I don't know the final answer, but it looks as if the last conditions don't necessarily fulfill in every case...

Also note that since $\,M\lhd G\,$ then $\,\Phi(M)\le\Phi(G)\;$ , so

$$M/\Phi(G)\cong\left(M/\Phi(M)\right)/\left(\Phi(G)/\Phi(M)\right)$$

so if $\,M\,$ is nilpotent then we already have that $\,M/\Phi(G)\;$ is nilpotent... and perhaps someone else can see something further from here.

Comment: Robinson's Course in the Theory of Groups has a nice result from Gaschütz on showing nilpotenty things are saturated: 5.2.15 page 131: If $H/\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent, then $H$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Thanks @JackSchmidt, that's interesting as I knew $\,H/\Phi(H)\;$ nilpotent $\;\implies H\;$ nilpotent. I shall check later whether this can help to simplify the above.